# HTML5 Video not playing in Safari on Localhost

Tags: safari

I have tested the video, an mp4 file created using Handbreak, on Safari by opening the file directly. Yet when it runs through localhost the file just shows a play arrow with no content.

This is true for both desktop and mobile Safari, yet Firefox and Chrome appear to work fine.

Here's my code:

```
    <video muted poster="/images/post.jpg" playsinline>
        <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, it turns out that this is a shortcoming of `python -m "SimpleHTTPServer"` that I was using to run the localhost server. So it seems Safari requires functionality that SimpleHTTPServer does not provide.

Thankfully, I was able to successfully use Node's version `http-server` which does appear to have the functionality Safari required.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I ran into this exact issue today. Do you know what exactly Safari is expecting from the webserver that isn't supported by `python -m http.server`? (that's what I ran)

Comment: No, I wasn't able to figure that out at the time.

Comment: Great answer! `npm install http-server` then `npx http-server --port 8080`